# Is there any way to make the cursor pointer for all onclick events in the page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, pointers, onclick

I want all the onclick ="location.href='some_url'" to have cursor pointer on hover. "some_url" will differ from event to event.

Note: I do not want to add ids or classes. or div:hover {cursor:pointer}

I want something like onclick [" "] {cursor:pointer}

and it should apply for all onclick events added in the project. Even jquery is fine for me.

Thanks,
Tharun.

Comment: Use the `:hover` modifier in CSS.

Comment: And having onclick in html elements is not a good practice. Use jQuery's .click or .on('click', ... or addEventListener in JS

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is not what I wanted, I do not want to add extra class or id because I have 100 onclick events in one page and many in a project. I have to add it in css so that it will be easy for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer. This will turn all your onClick events cursor to pointer.
You can use css or jQuery to achieve this. Below are the two types:

If you want to add in css.

```
[onClick] {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

If you want to add in jQuery.

`$( "[onClick]" ).css('cursor', 'pointer');`

Thanks, Tharun.

Comment: Your CSS solution works great for this code:

`<a onclick="clickFunction()">Click Me</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Html

```
<div>This is a Div</div>
```

Css

```
div:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use "a" tag for a big content div, anyways thank you.

Comment: If there are 100 divs with onclick event and a 100 without  onclick event, then how?

Comment: what u are expecting @TharunKumar

Comment: I am expecting where ever I write onclick event the cursor should be hover automatically. Is there any way for that?

Answer (score 0):

Like said, put `:hover` modifier in css. Like this :

```
#click_me:hover{
  cursor : pointer
}

or

.click_me:hover{
  cursor : pointer
}
```

CSS selector depends on your elements.

Comment: There shouldn't be a space before `:hover`.

Comment: Thank you, but i know this already. This is not what I wanted, I do not want to add extra class or id because I have 100 onclick evnts in one page and many in a project. I have to add it in css so that it will be easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><b><a href="javascript:;" id="link" target="_blank">This is a link</a></b></p>
```

//In jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#link').css('cursor', 'pointer');

or

$('#link').css('cursor', 'hand');
});
```

// In css

```
#link:hover  {       
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is not what I wanted, I do not want to add extra class or id because I have 100 onclick in one page and many in a project. I have to add it in css so that it will be easy for me.